# How can I find out the selected value of Radio Button List in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

aspx file:

I'm doing exams program. I view the answers in Radio Button List on Repeater . How can I find out the selected value of Radio Button List

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rep_CatQuestion" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Rep_CatQuestion_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="CatQuID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CatQuestionID") %>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFCount" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CatQuestionCount") %>' />

                                <asp:Repeater ID="Rep_Question" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Rep_Question_ItemDataBound">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="QuID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                                        <div class="row rowPadding">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                    <h6>
                                                        <%# Eval("QuestionText")%></h6>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <asp:RadioButtonList  ID="Rep_Answer" runat="server" DataTextField="AnswerText" DataValueField="AnswerID" >

                                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>

                                                        </div></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to get the selected value from RadioButtonList.

Comment: The problem is resolved through the use of sender in RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChanged Event                                                                                                  { RadioButtonList rblist = (RadioButtonList)sender;
            int aid = Convert.ToInt32(rblist.SelectedValue);}

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through repeater and find each RadioButtonList as

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Rep_CatQuestion.Items)
{
    string value = (item.FindControl("Rep_Answer") as RadioButtonList).SelectedValue;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added the code inside an event button. But Radio Button ID not work in this event.You are added the button into the repeater.

Comment: You have to loop through repeater and find each RadioButtonList